# Word for "person to ask"

Tags: questions, citation

I am making a data sheet with questions and answers. There's also a column for "Answerer" Which is a bit premature as many of these questions don't yet have answers. Not to mention it's a bit redundant and just kind of an awkward word in general.

I'm wondering if there is another word equating to "Person to ask"/"Source of the answer"/"Place to obtain a solution"?

Example of the data sheet - What else can I use as the first column header instead of "Answer Holder"?:

| *Answer holder* | *Question* | *Answer* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | Who is currently in charge of project X? |  |
| Organization B | What is the estimated time of work on this task Y? |  |
| Organization C directory | How many people are in organization C? |  |

Comment: Well, "respondent" is one possibility, though it has a contrary definition in law.

Comment: POC = Point of Contact.  One always goes to the POC for answers.

Comment: In a museum the one who is their for directions and questions is the *Docent*.

Comment: "Source of information" or just "source", maybe.

Comment: If you're strictly talking about questions and answers, with one person doing each, then _Addressee_ is the usual choice for the person answering the questions. The person asking them can be called either _Speaker_ or _Questioner_, but _Speaker_ is more general and applies everywhere. Or you could just represent them in print by _Q:_ and _A:_ .

Comment: @StuartF *Source* is good but I was hoping for a word that is specific to answers. A source might just as well refer to the question.

Comment: @Elliot *Docent* is definitely the kind of word I was hoping to hear :), but I think it's too domain specific in this case.

Comment: @JohnLawler *Addressee* is I think probably the right answer here, I'm not going to use it because it feels a bit stuffy but it is a single word that captures the intent.

Comment: @Jim *POC* I prefer the most, even though it's not a single word the phrase is cohesive and the abbreviation is well known (with some risk).

Comment: Oh, _addressee_ is an unambiguous technical term (like _speaker_), which I spose does make it stuffy. It's all technical stuff here.

Comment: I think the difference is that the *addressee* is the person being asked, which is potentially different from who *should* be asked.